# How to invite Facebook friends to my mobile app using custom UI?

Tags: facebook

I've seen this question.

[Invite Facebook friends to my iOS app that is not a game with custom UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633660/invite-facebook-friends-to-my-ios-app-that-is-not-a-game-with-custom-ui)

I'm developing a game app but has no Canvas, so I can't use `invitable_friends` API either.

Is it still impossible?
It looks like Instagram is doing this, but how do they make it possible?

[image: Invite Facebook Friends in Instagram]

Anyone know the solution ?

Comment: _“It looks like Instagram is doing this, but how do they make it possible?”_ – presumably by _being owned by Facebook_ ... No, there is no way for you to do this in a non-canvas app. What alternatives there are for “inviting” people is explained here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_1291953124230220 - but users will have to chose their friends themselves by starting to type their names, you can not offer such a custom friend selector using those ways.

Comment: I see... thanks for your answer!